# Может ли свойство класса быть одновременно static и private?

Tags: javascript

Может ли свойство класса быть одновременно static и private?

```js
class CGame
{
    static #varibles = ['truth', 'action'];

    constructor() {}

    #getRandomVarible()
    {
        const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) % 2;

        return CGame.#varibles[num];
    }
}
```

Comment: Как бы может, но  особо смысл в этом сложно придумать)

Comment: У меня есть класс, и в таком свойстве хранится массив из двух элементов. Я его сделал изначально статичным, а потом подумал.. Зачем он снаружи, почему бы и приватным не сделать. И вот как-то не знаю..

Comment: Если он нужен внутри и это состояние - то и статикой он не должен быть

Comment: Ну у меня как получается.. мне нужно рандомно получить либо одно либо второе.

Comment: Я обновил код в вопросе.

Comment: Если этот массив не планируется менять, я бы вообще сделал бы его константой, а может быть и вынес бы запределы класса, если потребуется его использовать еще где-то. В данном случае, как заметил @АлексейШиманский это не внутреннее состояние класса. А для статики - это тоже не сильно подходит, так как это не свойство класса, которое специфично для всего класса. Это просто массив каких-то данных.

Comment: что мешает просто вставить массив в getRandomVarible где он не будет виден?

Comment: Объясню немного.. В моем понимании static переменные "инициализируются" при "запуске" кода. То есть у каждого экземпляра не будет создаваться свойство каждый раз. Объявляя переменную внутри метода, она будет каждый раз так сказать перезаписываться (опять же в моем понимании). И да, мне нужно данное свойство только для одного метода и это свойство не будет изменяться.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с комментаторами, что конкртено в вашем случае (скорее всего) - это не тот случай, когда надо испольовать `static` и `private` вместе. Если это чисто внутри класса используется, то стоит убрать `static`. Но опять таки по коду (как минимум лично мне) трудно так судить, зачем вам этот массив и как `static` и как `private`.

Но для примера приведу вариант, когда в целом это может быть полезно:

```js
class GameObject {
  static #nextId = 16;
  #id;
  
  constructor() {
    this.#id = GameObject.#nextId++;
  }
  
  get id() {
    return this.#id;
  }
}

const gameObjects = [];

for(let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  gameObjects[i] = new GameObject();
}

const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

console.log(randomIndex, gameObjects[randomIndex].id);
```

Так у каждого игрового объекта будет свой уникальный `id`, который можно только получить, но не менять и он будет автомастически создаваться, при каждом создании каждого нового игрового объекта, так что и передавать ничего лишнего не надо будет

Ещё один пример, когда я использую `static` и `private` вместе постоянно - это когда создаю что-то типа `enum`:

```js
class Values {
  static #ONE = 'one';
  static get ONE() {
    return this.#ONE;
  }
  
  static #TWO = 'two';
  static get TWO() {
    return this.#TWO;
  }
  
  // На самом деле тут можно обойтись и без объявления
  // статичного и приватного поля, но мне так привычнее,
  // когда get и set работают именно с полями класса
  
  static get NO_FIELD() {
    return 'no field';
  }
}

console.log(Values.ONE);
console.log(Values.TWO);
console.log(Values.NO_FIELD);
```